# "Update required " error while making connection with OPEN VPN in iOS app

Tags: openvpn

[image]

I'm implementing an OpenVPN connection. But I'm facing "update required" error when I'm giving the VPN permission from alert under the tab setting >> VPN in red color

what to do? I'm facing that error for the last two days.

Comment: Try asking this question on https://superuser.com/

Comment: Did you find anything?